# Deploy YOLO on Intel GPU

Tags: deep-learning, intel, yolo

How to deploy YOLO on Intel (integrated) GPU? I tried (still trying actually) DirectML, but I should know C level programming for that. Is there any better/easier way to deploy YOLO on Intel GPU?

Answer (score 0):

For whoever looking for the solution:

- Install [OpenVino](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html) and follow all the instruction for installation.
- Follow [this guide](https://github.com/TNTWEN/OpenVINO-YOLOV4) to convert yolo weights into OpenVino format and run/deploy YOLO on Intel CPU/GPU.